# Yii - Error on adding foreign Keys using migrate

Tags: php, yii

I have created a migration using `migrate create` and put following codes on it:

```
<?php

class m131220_121449_create_all_tables extends CDbMigration
{   
    // Use safeUp/safeDown to do migration with transaction
    public function safeUp() {
        // MEMBERS TABLE
        $this->createTable("members", array(
            'uniq_id' => 'pk',
            'personel_num' => 'int(10) NOT NULL',
            'password' => 'string NOT NULL',
            'name' => 'string DEFAULT NULL',
            'lastupdate' => 'timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP',
        ), 'ENGINE=InnoDB');

        // RESERVED TABLE
        $this->createTable("reserved", array(
                'uniq_id' => 'pk',
                'personel_num' => 'int(10) NOT NULL',
                'RsvdDay' => 'date NOT NULL',
                'date_created' => 'timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP',
        ), 'ENGINE=InnoDB');

        // Add Foreign Keys Relations for RESERVED
        $this->addForeignKey("fk_rsvd_user", "reserved", "personel_num", "members", "personel_num", "CASCADE", "RESTRICT");
        }

}
```

But when I want to up this migration I got General Error #1005 when it tries to create Foreign Keys.

Here is the image of error:
[image: Error Image]

---

**The answer was found**:

The **reference** of a foreign key has to be a **Primary Key** in other table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$this->createTable("members", array(
        'uniq_id' => 'pk',
        'personel_num' => 'int(10) NOT NULL',
        'password' => 'string NOT NULL',
        'name' => 'string DEFAULT NULL',
        'lastupdate' => 'timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP',
        'UNIQUE KEY `personel_num` (`personel_num`)',
    ), 'ENGINE=InnoDB');
```

Make personel_num unique to make it a foreign key. You could also just remove uniq_id and make personel_num a pk.